# Guzzle post is not working with external ip. Throws Failed to connect to 37.XX.XX.XXX port 80: Connection timed out

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I know there is lots of answer to this question but it didn't work.

Guzzle version(s) affected: 6.3

PHP version: 7.2.24

cURL version: 7.58.0

Using guzzle in laravel project.
Everything is working properly when it is on local IP. Port 80 is open for the connections.
But when external (static)l IP is used it shows me the following error
Failed to connect to 37.XX.XX.XXX port 80: Connection timed out

Although when the same URL is used directly to the browser or postman then it works with external IP. I have done a google and tried but nothing works.

I have tried with plain curl also. Below is code.

```
$postData = [
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'client_id'     => 10,
            'client_secret' => 'xHuxxxxxxxflw',
            'username'      => 'admin@abc.com',
            'password'      => 'abc',
            'scope'         => '*',
        ];
        $ch     = curl_init();
        $url = 'http://37.XX.XX.XXX/oauth/token';
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
        if ($curl_errno > 0) {
                echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
        } else {
                echo "Data received\n";
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        echo ($data);
```

which shows me below error

```
cURL Error (7): Failed to connect to 37.XX.XX.XXX port 80: Connection timed out
```

Can anyone help me? I have spent lots of time to solve but nothing works.

Comment: Can you show your code? Have you tried plain cUrl instead?

Comment: @Justinas i have updated my question with plain cUrl. it doesn't working.

Comment: Does it allow `http` and `https` requests?

Comment: yes it allows http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved by allowing outbound ports. The outbound port was not allowed so it is not connecting the requests.